# Julia Linear Regression

Tags: julia

I was trying to fit a linear regression in Julia.
I have a data frame with 10 columns. The first 9 columns are the predictors
I call it X and the last column is the response variable I call it Y

I typed `linreg(X, Y)` But I get an error message saying
linreg has no method matching DataFrame and DataArray Float.

I was wondering how I could fix the issue.
I was thinking of converting X to a data Array

I tried `convert(X, Array)` But that threw an error as well: 
'Convert has no method matching convert'
Does anyone have any suggestions

Comment: I just tagged R and python because people who use R and Python are often familiar with linear regression. So I thought they could offer some useful suggestions.

Answer (score 18):

If you already have your data in a `DataFrame`, you should take a look at the [GLM.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/GLM.jl) package.

Specifically the `lm` function should do what you want and feel *very* familiar if you are an R user.

If you post more code (maybe which columns in your `DataFrame` store `X` and `Y`) we could help you further.

Answer (score 5):

> update: have to use `dot` operator in Julia 1.0 while performing scalar addition on arrays. i.e. `y = m*x .+ b`

You can also do linear regression using simple linear algebra.
Here is an example:

```
# Linear Algebra style
# For single linear regresion y= mx .+ b
m = 3.3; b = 2; x = rand(100,1)
y = m * x .+ b
# add noise
yn= y + randn(size(y)) * 0.5

# regression
X = zeros(100,2); X[:,1] = x;  X[:,2] = 1.0
coeff_pred = X\yn

slope =  round(coeff_pred[1], 2)
intercept = round(coeff_pred[2], 2)

println("The real slope is $m, and the predicted slope is $slope")
println("The real intercept is $b, and the predicted slope is $intercept")
```

Comment: This seems like slow version of Liner Regression, Can't we write fast one and Custom made?

Answer (score 3):

You are just using `convert` wrong. The correct syntax is `convert(T, x)` it reads: convert `x` to a value of type `T`.

so basically you need to do:

```
linreg(convert(Array,X),convert(Array,Y))
```

and it should work.